# Is $\Bbb{Z}_{m}=\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z} $?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that $$\Bbb{Z}_{p}=\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z} $$  where $p$ is prime. Is $\Bbb{Z}_{m}=\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}$, where $m\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yes. It is the additive group of classes $\mod m$. See here: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Additive_Group_of_Integers_Modulo_m

Comment: For some this is the definition. For others it can be proved that it is isomorphic.

Comment: Be careful, @Sigur. It could be the ring of integers, modulo $m$, too. The context here is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Careful! It depends what context you are in. Sometimes $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is used to denote the $p$-adic integers. Many times, however, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is used to denote the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb{Z}_{m}$ usually either denotes $\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}$ or the m-adic integers. In your case $\Bbb{Z}_{m}=\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}$ is simply notation.